# setting up PHP 7 to connect to SQL server 2014

Tags: php

I have both a development PC and windows server that run PHP. I'm trying to configure them for SQL server. I've downloaded SQL Server 2014 express and it's running on both.

The Development box box: 64-bit windows 7 PC, running IIS 7.5 and PHP 7.1.3 
The server is 64-bit windows server 2008 running PHP version 7.1.3

I've started with the dev box and tried downloading the drivers and modifying the php.ini to add the extension.

The drivers is not loading when I run phpinfo().  With some further research, I think I have not got the correct version of the driver for my dev box. I'm currently using php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll as my extension, but the installation media for the driver came with several .dll files and I'm not sure I have the right one. I did notice that the installation file I downloaded was SQLSRV30.EXE. I also noticed that there was SQLSRV52.EXE, but that does not support win 7. Can someone point me to the correct driver for my dev box and server.

I'm getting so frustrated with this because it's not self explanatory.

Comment: Just noticed that PHP is version 7.2.1 not 7.1.3

Comment: So I spent the day researching things and think it's a driver version error. I found the windows version of SQL driver for PHP and installed it. Now I get a new error: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match.  what is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are no SQL drivers for PHP 7.2 that work under windows 7. I had to downgrade to PHP 7.1 and then the drivers loaded and worked.

Comment: You can try to download xampp with the the desired PHP-version and use that. You still have to link then to that version in the configuration of IIS. It's already compiled, so you've to try perhaps only 2 or 3 xampp-versions to reach the target. I use from xampp usually only apache and php, it can be combined with any database as long as the drivers are present.

Comment: BTW: I don't install xampp, I have many versions and just use the batch-files to start what I need. But you never have even to do that, you've just to reference PHP in IIS correct.